# How to get the maximum number?

Tags: python

Ok so i have to find the maximum number from the file and i have 2 line with numbers

Now i want to find the maximum number and my code is also working fine but the issue is its showing the maximum number

Comment: The indentation is unintelligible. Please [edit] the question and fix it

Comment: To clarify on roganjosh's comment, it is unclear if the method `reducer` should be a file method or a method of class `MRNumbrCounter`. In addition, this code will not run as there are indentation errors.

Comment: `yield word, [line]`  in mapper ? and `sum( [line], [otherline])` should create `[line, otherline]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob

class MRNumberCounter(MRJob):

    def mapper(self, key, line):
        for number in line.split():
            yield number, 1         

    def combiner(self, number, occurrences):
        yield number, sum(occurrences)

    def reducer(self, number, occurrences):
        yield number, sum(occurrences)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MRNumberCounter.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

In `mapper`

```
yield word, line
```

In `reducer`

```
yield word, occurrences
```

and it will create `word [line, otherline]`

---

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob

class MRWordCounter(MRJob):

    def mapper(self, key, line):
        line = line.strip()
        for word in line.split(","):
            yield word, line

    def reducer(self, word, occurrences):
        yield word, occurrences

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MRWordCounter.run()
```

---

**EDIT:** This version use second `step` with new `reducer` to sort results

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob
from mrjob.step import MRStep

class MRLineGrouperAndSorter(MRJob):

    def steps(self):
        return [
            MRStep(
                mapper=self.mapper,
                reducer=self.reducer
            ),
            MRStep(
                reducer=self.reducer_sort
            )
        ]

    def mapper(self, key, line):
        line = line.strip()   # remove some spaces in line
        words = line.split(",")
        #line = ",".join(sorted(words)) # sorting words in lines
        for word in words:
            yield word, line

#    def combiner(self, word, values):
#        for line in values:
#            yield word, line

    def reducer(self, word, values):
        yield None, (word, values)  # use `None` (or other value) for all items and next reducer will get all items in one list

    def reducer_sort(self, key, values):  # key is None, values is [(word, values), (word, values), ...]
        for word, line in sorted(values):
            yield word, line

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MRLineGrouperAndSorter.run()
```

Comment: Thank alot mate the output is correct but how to do it in alphabetical order. like first we show for dolphin then for cat then for chicken and then for dog and so on.

Comment: it would need second `step` with new `reducer`. In current step `reducer` doesn't have access to all lines at once - it has only access to lines with the same `word` (`word, line`) - so it can't sort them. In second step it would use `None,(word,line)` so all values would use the same `None` and `reduce` would get all data at once. I 'm working on example.

Comment: new example in answer - it sort results.